# Date Type converter in room android

Tags: android, android-room

```
class CrimeTypeConverters {

@TypeConverter
fun fromDate(date: Date?): Long? {
    return date?.time
}

@TypeConverter
fun toDate(millisSinceEpoch: Long?): Date? {
    return millisSinceEpoch?.let {
        Date(it)
    }
}



 @TypeConverter
    fun toUUID(uuid: String?): UUID? {
        return UUID.fromString(uuid)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromUUID(uuid: UUID?): String? {
        return uuid?.toString()
    }
}
```

I am learning the android room and got stuck in this part. Can anyone explain about these functions? How do they work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Room when you have some variables which they are not primitive like objects such as Date or whatever object that is not int or long ,... you have to create a type converter.
type converter task is to convert your object to a primitive type to help room for storing it in Sqlite and convert stored primitive type to first class type when you want to read your data.

for example when your data is Date when Room want to save it, converter will convert it to long (timestamp is a long number) and when want to read create a Date from long timestamp.

Comment: Yes i got that but i am asking about the actual function logic

Comment: i explained the first one in the answer (timestamp) the second one save Id string and then on retrieve create Id from saved String

Answer (score 0):

Room provides functionality for converting between primitive and boxed types but doesn't allow for object references between entities.

Please refer this link [Use type converters](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data#type-converters)